# Calculate status bar height/real browser height in Android stock browser using pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, browser, height, statusbar

I need to find out available height for Android stock browser: screen height - status bar height. I tried:

```
this.initialHeight = (window.innerHeight < window.innerWidth ? window.innerHeight : window.innerWidth);
```

Also tried:

```
this.initialHeight = (window.outerHeight < window.outerWidth ? window.outerHeight : window.outerWidth);
```

But both of them gave me same results (360 in landscape mode). How can I find real available height for browser with pure javascript?